# Why should not past perfect be used here?

Tags: tense, difference, usage

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazhar_Khan_(actor,_born_1955))

> Before his death, Zeenat filed for divorce.

Since, we are talking of two events with one occurring before the other, we should use the following structure:

> Before his death, Zeenat **had** filed for divorce.

Am i wrong?

What should be my approach to get acquainted with all these grammar concepts?

Comment: Either is correct, since time relations are quite clearly set by using "before"

Comment: What's the difference then?